# How to find a constant, K, for a probability mass function in 2 variables, where the variables depend on each other

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I am given the function:

$$f(x,y)=3Ky$$ $$ 0\leq y\leq x \leq 1$$

And is zero when not on the given interval. I have been asked to find K such that the function above is a Probability Mass Function on the interval given. However, my textbook suggests the answer should be a constant. Mine is not:

$$\int_{y}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}3Kx dydx = \frac{3K}{6}(1 - y^3) = 1$$

$$K = \frac{2}{1 - y^3}$$

Of course, integrating it the other way around would yield and answer for K in terms of x. I am not sure what - if anything - I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you definite integrate it according to $y$, then the result can't depended to $y$ any more and the second boundaries must be independent of it:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y) dydx = 1 = \int_0^1 \int_y^1 f(x,y) dxdy$$
Now you can continue to find **constant** $K$.

Comment: Thank you very much.